# UBUNTU 20.04 on Raspberry Pi 4/8GB, direct boot from SSD

Tags: raspberrypi

This is more a question for UBUNTU developers...i think ?
Since ***Raspberry Pi 4*** just made it possible to boot directly ***from SSD drive***(via USB3),
***instead*** of using ***micro SD card*** ...

It is fair to ask, when will be this possible with UBUNTU 20.04..

Do we need to wait for **new version of UBUNTU..?**
or this will be possible with some **package updates/upgrades?**

Hope for some direct answer(s)

***Thank You so much in advance...!***

**P.S.**

*[Raspberry Pi forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=131&t=278129&p=1686486#p1686486)*

Comment: Clarification: The Pi Forums thread is about bootloading an already-installed system, not about a Live installer for ARM.

Comment: Thank You for warning.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install and run Ubuntu x64 on pi4-8gb  from a usb ssd by :

- Upgrade bootloader instructions: https://peyanski.com/stable-raspberry-pi-4-usb-boot/ (remember to copy all elf and dat files)
- Install ubuntu on the usb (you can use etcher or raspberry imager)
- Overwrite elf and dat files (with the ones save earlier)
- Decompress vmlinuz, instructions here https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=131&t=278791
- if you want to use WIFI you can setup SSID and pass in the network-config file and after boot issue the following commands :

  - *sudo netplan --debug try* (to check for errors)
  - *sudo netplan --debug apply* (to apply the config)

You can check the IP using *ip addr show*

If you plan to use a SSD via USB 3 ports do yourself a favor and get a adapter with UASP (explication here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0kYcM1E5fY )

L.E. After install and update I made an image of the SSD. Restoring that image will be way faster then all the steps mentioned above (if you use linux you can make image a drive using gnome-disk-utility).

Sorry for all the links ...

Comment: While this may technically be an answer, the links you've provided could die.  As a result, those items could get *lost* and the answer would become unuseful.  Please provide the instructions here directly rather than link to other sites.

Comment: Would be lovely for an updated image from Canonical. 20.10 which already supports booting from USB proves that 20.04 could be updated similar. I hope 20.04.2 will be.